# Slow Firestore Queries in Flutter Web After Version Upgrade

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-dependencies

I recently upgraded my Flutter web application from version 3.13.7 to the latest one, and since then, I've been experiencing significant slowdowns in Firestore queries. In my production environment, the queries that used to take 1-2 seconds are now taking around 30 seconds, resulting in server timeouts.

## Here are some key details:

The queries are fetching 12 documents from a Firestore collection, totaling around 72.65 KB of data.
This issue is consistent across both the production and test environments.
I've verified that the problem started after the Flutter version upgrade.
Interestingly, any release of the application before the version upgrade works normally, with queries taking 1-2 seconds.
Even when using the exact production release from my Git repository, the slow query issue persists.
Firestore Query Code Snippet:

```
var querySnapshot = FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('articles')
    .orderBy('pub_date', descending: true)
    .limit(12)
    .get();
```

## Additional Information:

- **Flutter Version Before Upgrade:** 3.13.7
- **Flutter Version After Upgrade:** Latest version
- **Cloud Firestore Version:** 4.12.2

I'm seeking guidance on where the problem might be originating—whether it's in my Flutter web application, Firestore, or somewhere else. Any suggestions or insights on how to troubleshoot and resolve this performance issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Attempted Solutions:**

- I tried downgrading the Flutter version back to 3.13.7, but it did not resolve the issue.
- I even checked exact version for firestore related packages in the .idea/library Flutter_Plugin.xml and Dart_Packages.xml file.
- Made a demo project, integrated the firestore again with minimal code even then it was not working.